# Shell command for inserting a newline every nth element of a huge line of comma separated strings

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have a one line csv containing a lot of elements. Now I want to insert a newline after every n-th element in a bash/shell script.

Bonus: I'd like to prepend a line with descriptors and using the count of descriptors as 'n'.

Example:

```
"4908041eee3d4bf98e606140b21ebc89.16","7.38974601030349731","45.31298584267982221","94ff11ce7eb54642b0768dde313e8b25.16","7.38845318555831909","45.31425320325949713", (...)
```

into

```
"id","lon","lat"
"4908041eee3d4bf98e606140b21ebc89.16","7.38974601030349731","45.31298584267982221"
"94ff11ce7eb54642b0768dde313e8b25.16","7.38845318555831909","45.31425320325949713"
(...)
```

Edit: I made a first attempt, but the comma delimiters are missing then:

```
(...) | xargs --delimiter=',' -n3

"4908041eee3d4bf98e606140b21ebc89.16" "7.38974601030349731" "45.31298584267982221"
"94ff11ce7eb54642b0768dde313e8b25.16" "7.38845318555831909" "45.31425320325949713"
```

trying to replace the " " with ","

```
(...) | xargs --delimiter=',' -n3 -i echo ${{}//" "/","}
-bash: ${{}//\": bad substitution
```

Comment: Show us what you attempted.

Comment: | xargs --delimiter=',' -n3 but that removes the commas

Comment: Edit your post and add the command and the output you got so that you can get help debugging/fixing

Comment: You state that you want to "insert a newline", but from your example it appears you actually want to replace every third comma with a newline.  Precision in specifying a problem can often help you find the solution.

Comment: Thanks everyone for various all working solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Note: What distinguishes this solution is that it derives the number of output columns from the number of columns in the header line.</sup>

Assuming that the fields in your CSV input have no *embedded* `,` instances (in which case you'd need a proper CSV parser), try `awk`:

```
awk -v RS=, -v header='"id","lon","lat"' '
  BEGIN { 
    print header
    colCount = 1 + gsub(",", ",", header) 
  }
  { 
    ORS = NR % colCount == 0 ? "\n" : ","
    print
  }
' file.csv
```

Note that if the input file ends with a newline (as is typical), you'll get an extra newline trailing the output.

With *GNU* Awk or Mawk (but *not* BSD/OSX Awk, which only supports literal, single-character `RS` values), you can fix this as follows:

```
awk -v RS='[,\n]' -v header='"id","lon","lat"' '
  BEGIN { 
    print header
    colCount = 1 + gsub(",", ",", header) 
  }
  { 
    ORS = NR % colCount == 0 ? "\n" : ","
    print
  }
' file.csv
```

BSD/OSX Awk workaround: stick with `-v RS=,` and replace `file.csv` with `<(tr -d '\n' < file.csv)` in order to remove all newlines from the *input* first.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with Perl for that!

Let's assume this outputs something like your file:

```
printf "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" 

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Then you could use this if you wanted every 4th comma replaced:

```
printf "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" | perl -pe 's{,}{++$n % 4 ? $& : "\n"}ge'
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10
```

Comment: Same here :), I would go with perl for that :)

Answer (score 4):

```
cat data.txt | xargs -n 3 -d, | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

With **n=3** here and input filename is called **data.txt**

Comment: ++ for a pragmatic solution that fixes the OP's solution attempt; general caveat: only works if the input fields have no embedded whitespace (which apparently _is_ true for the OP's data).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input file is named `input`:

```
echo id,lon,lat; awk '{ORS=NR%3?",":"\n"}1' RS=, input
```